# How to solve Turing Machine example for anbncn / n>=1?

Tags: turing-machines

Can anyone tell me whether my answer is right or not for this example of Turing Machine??

Q. Construct Turing Machine for L={ anbncn / n>=1 }

Ans: Transition function for string aabbcc

```
^(q1,a)=(X,q2,R)
^(q2,a)=(a,q2,R)
^(q2,b)=(Y,q3,R)
^(q3,b)=(b,q3,R)
^(q3,c)=(Z,q4,L)
^(q4,b)=(b,q4,L)
^(q4,Y)=(Y,q4,L)
^(q4,a)=(a,q4,L)
^(q4,X)=(X,q1,R)
^(q1,a)=(X,q2,R)
^(q2,Y)=(Y,q2,R)
^(q2,b)=(Y,q3,R)
^(q3,Z)=(Z,q3,R)
^(q3,c)=(Z,q4,L)
^(q4,Z)=(Z,q4,L)
^(q4,Y)=(Y,q4,L)
^(q4,Y)=(Y,q4,L)
^(q4,X)=(X,q1,R)
^(q1,Y)=(Y,q2,R)
^(q2,Y)=(Y,q2,R)
^(q2,Z)=(Z,q2,R)
^(q2,Z)=(Z,q2,R)
^(q2,B)=(B,q5,N)
```

Can anyone tell me whether its correct or not??
Or should I have to make changes in it??

Answer (score 0):

It seems correct
The idea is:
Turn the first *a* to X, then go right to find the first *b*, turn it to *Y*, go right to find the first *c*, turn it to *Z*, get back to the first *a* again.
The process goes on until the first letter under the head is *Y* instead of *a*. It means that all *a*'s have been matched with *b*'s and *c*'s.
The head then needs to go right, passes *Y*'s and *Z*'s till it reaches a blank.